# MYSQL third inner join not working

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have written a query as below but getting an error

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.host, 
 T3.error
FROM table1 T1
INNER JOIN table2 T2
ON
T1.item_id = T2.item_id
INNER JOIN table3 T3
ON
T1.ID = T3.run_id 
and T1.submit_id = (select max(T1.submit_id) from table1 T1) 
;
```

Here, `T3.run_id = (select max(T3.run_id) from T3)` is giving an error

I have three rows in `T3` for `max(T3.run_id)` for a particular `T1.item_id = T2.item_id`

```
item_id  host
15907    abc.com
7303     cde.com
7304     abcd.com
7305     cdedf.com
```

Above is sample Data for `table 2`
`select * from table2 where item_id = '15907';`

```
id  submit_id   item_id
49898   16693   15907
49899   16693   15907
49900   16693   15907
53735   17972   15907
53736   17972   15907
53737   17972   15907
```

Above is sample Data for `table 1`
`select * from table1 where item_id = '15907';`

Above I need to select rows with `max(submit_id)` and `T1.item_id = T2.item_id`
In this example, it would be `17972`

```
id  run_id  error
12345   53735   error1
12345   53735   error2
12346   53735   error3
12347   53736   error4
12348   53736   error5
12349   53737   error6
```

Above is sample Data for `table3`
`select * from table3 where run_id IN ('53735', '53736', '53737');`

I am getting 0 rows as an output

Comment: Please include sample data, table definitions and your expected output in your question

Comment: What is error saying? Is T3 in "(select max(T3.run_id) from T3) " actual table or are you trying to use an alias previously defined in this query?

Comment: It is not enough to say "I'm getting an error".  Without that error, we don't know what the error says.  The error is a description of the problem, and you are keeping that from us.

Comment: added all details including sample data in my question

Comment: Hey @meallhour in the  select max(T1.submit_id) from T1. here T1 is a alias name but not the table thats why you are getting the error. instead of T1 use   (select max(submit_id) from table1).

Comment: Try changing "select max(T1.submit_id) from T1" into "select max(T1.submit_id) from table1 T1"

Comment: thanks changed the query but now i am getting 0 rows. Also edited my question

Comment: where is the create date column details in table1 and status details in table3

Comment: taken out those fields from main query to make it easier. edited question. I am stuck with correcting `T1.submit_id = (select max(T1.submit_id) from table1 T1) `

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite you query as below to get the expected output

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.host,T3.error
FROM table2 T2
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT a.*
    FROM table1 a
    LEFT JOIN table1 b ON a.item_id = b.item_id AND a.submit_id < b.submit_id
    WHERE b.submit_id IS NULL
) T1  ON T1.item_id = T2.item_id
INNER JOIN table3 T3 ON T1.ID = T3.run_id
```

I have moved table1 in inner query to get the ids where `submit_id` is maximum

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/QZA52874)

Answer (score 0):

check the below out put

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.host 
     ,T3.error
    FROM table1 T1
    INNER JOIN table2  T2 ON T1.item_id = T2.item_id
    and T1.submit_id = (select max(T1.submit_id) from table1  T1 )
    INNER JOIN table3 T3 ON T1.ID = T3.run_id 
    ;
```

output

```
host    error
abc.com error1
abc.com error2
abc.com error3
abc.com error4
abc.com error5
abc.com error6
```